# MySQL Using Pow() for table data

Tags: mysql

I need to have 3 columns in a table called `prize`
Fields are: `Event_id`, `Place`, `Place`

I need to find the square root of the prize money divided by 2, round to a whole number and then display this in a column called `New_Money` with the 3 other columns (`Event_id`, `Place`, `Money`) without actually storing the `New_Money` data in a table. Oh, I also have to use the power function.

I started testing with:

```
SELECT ROUND(money*money/2) AS New_Money
FROM prize;
```

This gave me a column called `New_Money` with the correct data, but no other columns.
I couldn't work out how to get the other columns to display in the same string, AND this isn't using the `Pow()` function anyway.

I tested:

```
 SELECT pow(money,money) AS New_Money
 FROM prize;
```

But gave an error and is still "fetching" 5 minutes later....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using POW in a wrong way. Try this

```
SELECT  Event_id, Place, Money,pow(money,2)/2 AS New_Money FROM prize;
```

Comment: Thank you Ajay, worked a treat. I understand what i was doing wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT Event_id, Place, Money,ROUND(money*money/2) AS New_Money FROM prize;
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks, that gets all the information i need. However it specifies using the power function. I'll try incorperating it in there somehow..

Answer (score 0):

POW usage is wrong. Here is the query that you should use

```
SELECT Event_id, Place, Money, ROUND(POW(money, 2)/2) as New_Money
FROM prize;
```

Above query makes use of POW and rounds of the result after squaring maney and dividing it by 2.

Hope it helps...

[MySQl documentation for POW function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_pow)

Answer (score 0):

Their is [SQRT](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sqrt-function.htm) function available in `mysql` to find the SquareRoot, so you can easily find the result through:

```
SELECT  Event_id, Place, Money,ROUND(SQRT(money)/2) AS New_Money FROM prize;
```

Answer (score -1):

The best one I can suggest you that:.

```
SELECT *, ROUND(POW(money, 2)/2) AS new_money FROM prize;
```

Worked for me.